# Change the Clock's background color in material-ui pickers?

Tags: material-ui

I am using material-ui/pickers^3.2.6 with the material-ui theme primary color being gray and the background color of the Clock is also gray making the selected time circle and selected line disappear. Below is an image which shows it clearly. I need to override or change the clock background color so that the lines and functionality will show up. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Clock image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an MuiTheme, and override MuiPickersClock-clock backgroundColor property. 
After that wrap your component with ThemeProvider:

```
import React from "react";
import { KeyboardDateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiPickersClock: {
      clock: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
});

const StaticTimePicker = () => {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} >
       <KeyboardDateTimePicker
        label="Keyboard with error handler"
        onError={console.log}
        minDate={new Date("2018-01-01T00:00")}
        format="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"
       />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
     </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default StaticTimePicker;
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: I am understanding a little more about how to do the overrides based on your post so thank you for that. Side question still about changing the color of the buttons as you can see they are so light. I see on their site that they override the button color using this but I am getting an error trying to do the same thing. 

`const materialTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
        MuiPickersModal: {
           dialogAction: {
              color: lightBlue["400"],
      },
    },
  },
});`

Comment: The error is "Material-UI: you are trying to override a style that does not exist. Fix the 'dialogAction' key of 'theme.overrides.MuiPickersModal'.

Comment: this is tricky sometimes, and takes time to catch. I don't think MuiPickersModal exists. To check what style you need to override, open DevTools (f12 in chrome), and start inspecting the elements until you find the desired element. Change the color from the console to see it actually changes the text color of the button. and than, if the element className is for example "MuiButton-textPrimary", than your override should be: MuiButton: {
      textPrimary: {
        color: 'red',
      }
    }. I updated my CodeSandbox so you can play with it

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to override all primary buttons though. Their CSS overrides page has this as an example but it doesn't work there either. https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/css-overrides#override-example

Comment: They are using DatePicker, and we are using another component. On our component there is no dialogAction style, there is dialogRoot, but it doesn't affect the text color in the bottom section. That is since the bottom section is implemented using DialogActions. I don't think they provide any good way to override the buttons color.

Comment: Finally I found the solution I was looking for. Worked like a charm